# When does Base Class Injection happen in Micronaut

Tags: micronaut

I am using inheritance with micronaut. I have an application the does something similar to the following

```java
@Prototype
class ValueHolder {
    public void doSomthing();
}

@Prototype
class Base {
    @Inject
    ValueHolder value;

    Base() {
        // Does Something
    }

}

@Prototype
class Parent extends Base {

    Parent() {
         super()
         value.doSomthing(); // NullPointerException
    }
}
```

I would like to know why `value` is still `null` and if inheritance is an anti-pattern in micronaot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to know why value is still null and if inheritance is an
>   anti-pattern in micronaot.

Inheritance is not an anti-pattern in Micronaut.

The issue you are having doesn't really have anything to do with Micronaut.  It has more to do with how objects are allocated.  You are referencing `value` in the `Parent` constructor but it is impossible for `value` to have been initialized by then.  The code that will initialize the `value` property can't execute until the `Parent` instance is initialized, but you are trying to reference `value` before that happens.  You would see the same behavior if you leave Micronaut out of it and simply invoke `new Parent();`.

It is unclear what you need the `value` object to do when the `Parent` is being constructed but one option to consider is instead of this:

```
import io.micronaut.context.annotation.Prototype;

@Prototype
class Base {
    ValueHolder value;

    Base(ValueHolder value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

```
import io.micronaut.context.annotation.Prototype;

@Prototype
class Parent extends Base {

    Parent(ValueHolder value) {
        super(value);
        value.doSomthing(); // Not NullPointerException
    }
}
```